# 'this version of sdk is incompatible with server, please downgrade your sdk or upgrade your server' error when I try to connect to the milvus server

Tags: milvus, grpcio

I'm trying out Milvus implementations on a jupyter notebook, but I run into an error when I try to connect to the Milvus server. I'm attaching the cell and the corresponding error for reference. Note that I'm using pymilvus 2.2.9.

> Connect to Milvus service
> connections.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT)
>
> Create collection
> collection = create_milvus_collection(COLLECTION_NAME, DIM)
> print(f'A new collection created: {COLLECTION_NAME}')

Error:

> ### 2023-06-19 03:51:10,646 - 8380245248 - decorators.py-decorators:108 - ERROR: RPC error: [__internal_register], <MilvusException: (code=1, message=this version of sdk is incompatible with server, please downgrade your sdk or upgrade your server )>, <Time:{'RPC start': '2023-06-19 03:51:10.636182', 'RPC error': '2023-06-19 03:51:10.646730'}>
>
> _InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py:163, in upgrade_reminder..handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 162 try:
> 163     return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 164 except grpc.RpcError as e:
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py:1359, in GrpcHandler.__internal_register(self, user, host)
> 1358 req = Prepare.register_request(user, host)
> 1359 response = self._stub.Connect(request=req)
> 1360 if response.status.error_code != common_pb2.Success:
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py:247, in _UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.**call**(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
> 240 def **call**(self,
> 241              request: Any,
> 242              timeout: Optional[float] = None,
> (...)
> 245              wait_for_ready: Optional[bool] = None,
> 246              compression: Optional[grpc.Compression] = None) -> Any:
> 247     response, ignored_call = self._with_call(request,
> 248                                              timeout=timeout,
> 249                                              metadata=metadata,
> 250                                              credentials=credentials,
> 251                                              wait_for_ready=wait_for_ready,
> 252                                              compression=compression)
> 253     return response
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py:290, in _UnaryUnaryMultiCallable._with_call(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
> 287 call = self._interceptor.intercept_unary_unary(continuation,
> 288                                                client_call_details,
> 289                                                request)
> 290 return call.result(), call
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:379, in _InactiveRpcError.result(self, timeout)
> 378 """See grpc.Future.result."""
> 379 raise self
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py:274, in _UnaryUnaryMultiCallable._with_call..continuation(new_details, request)
> 273 try:
> 274     response, call = self._thunk(new_method).with_call(
> 275         request,
> 276         timeout=new_timeout,
> 277         metadata=new_metadata,
> 278         credentials=new_credentials,
> 279         wait_for_ready=new_wait_for_ready,
> 280         compression=new_compression)
> 281     return _UnaryOutcome(response, call)
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:1043, in _UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.with_call(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
> 1041 state, call, = self._blocking(request, timeout, metadata, credentials,
> 1042                               wait_for_ready, compression)
> 1043 return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, True, None)
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:910, in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
> 909 else:
> 910     raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
>
> _InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
> status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
> details = "unknown method Connect for service milvus.proto.milvus.MilvusService"
> debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:19530 {created_time:"2023-06-19T03:51:10.642309+05:30", grpc_status:12, grpc_message:"unknown method Connect for service milvus.proto.milvus.MilvusService"}"
>
> > 
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> MilvusException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py:120, in GrpcHandler._wait_for_channel_ready(self, timeout)
> 119 grpc.channel_ready_future(self._channel).result(timeout=timeout)
> 120 self._setup_identifier_interceptor(self._user)
> 121 return
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py:220, in GrpcHandler._setup_identifier_interceptor(self, user)
> 219 host = socket.gethostname()
> 220 self._identifier = self.__internal_register(user, host)
> 221 self._identifier_interceptor = interceptor.header_adder_interceptor(["identifier"], [str(self._identifier)])
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py:109, in error_handler..wrapper..handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 108     LOGGER.error(f"RPC error: [{inner_name}], {e}, Time:{record_dict}")
> 109     raise e
> 110 except grpc.FutureTimeoutError as e:
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py:105, in error_handler..wrapper..handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 104     record_dict["RPC start"] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
> 105     return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 106 except MilvusException as e:
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py:136, in tracing_request..wrapper..handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 135     self.set_onetime_request_id(req_id)
> 136 ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 137 return ret
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py:85, in retry_on_rpc_failure..wrapper..handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 84     else:
> 85         raise e
> 86 except Exception as e:
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py:50, in retry_on_rpc_failure..wrapper..handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 49 try:
> 50     return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 51 except grpc.RpcError as e:
> 52     # DEADLINE_EXCEEDED means that the task wat not completed
> 53     # UNAVAILABLE means that the service is not reachable currently
> 54     # Reference: https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc-status-code
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py:168, in upgrade_reminder..handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 166     msg = "this version of sdk is incompatible with server, please downgrade your sdk or upgrade your " 
> 167           "server "
> 168     raise MilvusException(message=msg) from e
> 169 raise e
>
> MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=1, message=this version of sdk is incompatible with server, please downgrade your sdk or upgrade your server )>
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> MilvusException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[7], line 2
> 1 # Connect to Milvus service
> 2 connections.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT)
> 4 # Create collection
> 5 collection = create_milvus_collection(COLLECTION_NAME, DIM)
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/orm/connections.py:349, in Connections.connect(self, alias, user, password, db_name, token, **kwargs)
> 345         if parsed_uri.scheme == "https":
> 346             kwargs["secure"] = True
> 349     connect_milvus(**kwargs, user=user, password=password, token=token, db_name=db_name)
> 350     return
> 352 # 2nd Priority, connection configs from env
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/orm/connections.py:282, in Connections.connect..connect_milvus(**kwargs)
> 279 t = kwargs.get("timeout")
> 280 timeout = t if isinstance(t, (int, float)) else Config.MILVUS_CONN_TIMEOUT
> 282 gh._wait_for_channel_ready(timeout=timeout)
> 283 kwargs.pop('password')
> 284 kwargs.pop("token", None)
>
> File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py:123, in GrpcHandler._wait_for_channel_ready(self, timeout)
> 121         return
> 122     except (grpc.FutureTimeoutError,  MilvusException) as e:
> 123         raise MilvusException(Status.CONNECT_FAILED,
> 124                               f'Fail connecting to server on {self._address}. Timeout') from e
> 126 raise MilvusException(Status.CONNECT_FAILED, 'No channel in handler, please setup grpc channel first')
>
> MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=2, message=Fail connecting to server on 127.0.0.1:19530. Timeout)>

I'm stuck, I had a grpcio issue when I was trying in colab asking me to downgrade my version to 1.53.0 and that did not work after downgrading either. I moved to jupyter and ran into what seems like a grpcio as well.

Answer (score 1):

As @FakeAlcohol mentioned from https://milvus.io/docs/install-pymilvus.md

> It is recommended to install a PyMilvus version that matches the version of the Milvus server you installed. For more information, see Release Notes.

At least the major.minor versions need to match between pymilvus and milvus server.

Like this, I can see my pymilvus: 2.3.6

```
!pip install pymilvus
import pymilvus
print(pymilvus.__version__)
```

For my local server, I can check Docker Desktop, click on the Container, mine is 2.3.7. [image]

2.3.6 will run on 2.3.7 because major.minor versions match.

In case you're running your Milvus on Zilliz, https://stackoverflow.com/a/78143787/11494504, you can check server version like this:

```
import os
from pymilvus import connections, utility

TOKEN = os.getenv("ZILLIZ_API_KEY")
# Connect to Zilliz cloud using endpoint URI and API key TOKEN.
CLUSTER_ENDPOINT="https://in03-48a5b11fae525c9.api.gcp-us-west1.zillizcloud.com:443"
connections.connect(
    alias='default',
    uri=CLUSTER_ENDPOINT,
    token=TOKEN,
) 

print(f"Server version: {utility.get_server_version()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with pymilvus==2.2.9. I used Jupyter Notebook too.

pip install pymilvus==2.2.5 solved the issue for me.
(If your. milvus version is 2.2.*)
https://pypi.org/project/pymilvus/

Answer (score 0):

The similar issue was resolved by upgrading the Milvus server to version 2.2.10 and reinstalling the related libraries: `pip3 install protobuf==3.20.0`, `pip3 install grpcio-tools`, and `pip3 install pymilvus==2.2.11`.

> It is recommended to install a PyMilvus version that matches the version of the Milvus server you installed. For more information, see Release Notes.

from
https://milvus.io/docs/install-pymilvus.md